# Custom valued Enum?

Tags: solidity

I have 2 variables that can take multiple values:

Shape:

- Circle: 2
- Triangle: 3
- Square: 4

Size:

- Small: 3
- Medium: 5
- Large: 8

I want to use something like `Shape.Square` & `Size.Large` in my contract. I was considering using enums but that would give me only int values from 0 with increments by 1. As can be seen above I want to **custom-define** values associated with these constants.

What data structure should I use? Should constants be a good solution? But, again I can't combine constants into groups of Shape & Size.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `structs` data type, which is a custom-defined data type that can group multiple variables in a single `struct` variable to form a new type. They are useful for grouping together related data.

See: https://solidity-by-example.org/structs/

Comment: Yes, but I can't define a constant struct. I have to create an instance of a struct & after that, the struct will be useless.